# SignalR authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have an ASP MVC5 application using the new Identity Security.My project is actually a simple chat application using signalR 2.0.3. Now the problem is that the client is done in VB that connects to the chat server (which is an ASP.NET MVC5 hosted SignalR server) and I need to authenticate the user (in VB) using the generated accountcontroller's login method. I did find an example in the signalR documentation but its not working i think because that was done for form authentication ; here is the code from signalR website (http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/hub-authorization)

```
private static bool AuthenticateUser(string user, string password, out Cookie authCookie)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.contoso.com/RemoteLogin") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    var authCredentials = "UserName=" + user + "&Password=" + password;
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authCredentials);
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        authCookie = response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    }

    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

(and then pass the cookie to hubconnection's cookie container )

is there any equivalent method that I can use to login my user using the accountcontroler/login method ? or there is an entirely different way of doing it for new Identity thing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might help https://github.com/gustavo-armenta/CookieAuthenticationSample

Comment: You can find a close equivalent to your AuthenticateUser method [here](https://github.com/gustavo-armenta/CookieAuthenticationSample#csharpclientcommonclientcs). The key difference between this and what you have is that the code I linked to makes two requests so it can send back the anti-forgery token that `AccountController.Login` expects by default. You can see how this is used in [CommonClient.cs](https://github.com/gustavo-armenta/CookieAuthenticationSample/blob/master/CSharpClient/CommonClient.cs).

Comment: thanks guys. i found a way of doing it. bu thanks for your responses!

Comment: It would be useful if you would post how you do it - so other people can learn from it

Comment: You should learn how to use jwt security in order to use signlar with authentication